# Can't find gem sass (>= 0.a) with executable sass

Tags: sass, gruntjs, rubygems

After recent OS update to High Sierra. I am having problems with SASS and Grunt.

When I run `grunt`

```
Running "sass:compressed" (sass) task
Traceback (most recent call last):
    2: from /usr/local/bin/sass:22:in `<main>'
    1: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:308:in `activate_bin_path'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:289:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem sass (>= 0.a) with executable sass (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
```

I have tried updating ruby and re-installing grunt:

```
> npm install grunt --save-dev
npm WARN grunt-contrib-imagemin@0.1.4 requires a peer of grunt@~0.4.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN grunt-contrib-sass@0.4.1 requires a peer of grunt@~0.4.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN grunt-contrib-uglify@0.2.7 requires a peer of grunt@~0.4.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN grunt-contrib-watch@0.4.4 requires a peer of grunt@~0.4.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN wb2012@0.0.0 No license field.
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Not sure why, but I had to reinstall sass `gem install sass` and it fixed it.

Comment: got the same trouble with jekyll and that does not works for me.

Comment: I had same issue after running `brew update; brew upgrade; brew unlink php71; brew uninstall php71; brew install php72;`. sass update helped.

Answer (score 1):

this `sudo gem install sass -n /usr/local/bin` fixed it for me!